# Фактическая разница между наследованием и объявлением как члена класса

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

Равнозначны ли эти два примера:

```
class a {};
class b: public a {};
```

и

```
class a{};
a x;
class b
{
public:
    a x;
};
```

Comment: @oasistravels,  какой язык ?

Comment: в первом случае - наследование, во втором - композиция

Comment: @eicto, C++ же

Comment: Что значит «равноценны»? Разный код, работает по-разному.

Answer (score 2):

в первом случае класс **b** открыто наследует класс **a**. Во втором случае вы создаете экземпляр класса **a**.

Comment: Чо-чо? Вообще вопрос, конечно, задан некорректно. Но ответ тоже не идет до уровня технических подробностей. Ведь, действительно, при наследовании базовый класс "как бы" включается в класс-потомок.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ: не равнозначны. 
Попробую объяснить на пальцах.

```
class a {};
class b: public a {};
```

В этом коде класс b открыто наследуется от класса a, а значит наследует и интерфейс и реализацию класса a. В данном случае можно говорить, что b - является разновидностью класса a. Если проецировать на автопром, то можно смело сказать, что Audi A6 является автомобилем

```
class Auto {};
class AudiA6 : public Auto {};
```

Во втором примере можно говорить о композиции:

```
class a{};
a x;
class b
{
public:
    a x;
};
```

Тут можно говорить о том, что класс b реализуется посредствам класса а, либо класс b содержит в себе класс a.
Пример: любой автомобиль имеет под капотом двигатель за счет которого может совершать работу:

```
class Engine {};
class Auto {
private:
    Engine* m_engine;
};
```

некорректно сказать, что автомобиль - разновидность двигателя, но совершенно очевидно, что двигатель - составная часть автомобиля.

Такая вот разница, надеюсь, эти примеры хоть немного приоткроют завесу тайны.

Answer (score 1):

[@oasistravels](/users/15589/oasistravels), Вам просто нужно почитать про отношения между объектами ( has-a, is-a ) и такие вопросы отпадут. Неплохо об этом у [Солтера](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0wnRBEOwswgME05SUN5RndIQ3c/edit?usp=sharing) написано. Вобще советую почитать, но если Вы новичок, то скорее лучше будет начать с [Дейтела](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3592139/).

P.S. Прошу прощения за качество pdf'ки.